# Какую структуру данных выбрать, чтобы быстро перебрать данные в цикле?

Tags: java, массивы, алгоритм, нейронные-сети

У меня есть нейросеть и веса хранятся в синапсах. Дело в том что для каждого веса идёт много дополнительной информации. Синапсы это связь между нейронами и их может быть много. У меня есть два стула для хранения данных:

Первый стул:

```
    class Synaps{
        float w[];
        float a[];
        int source[];
        int dst[];
        ...
    }
```

Второй стул:

```
    class Synaps {
        float w, a;
        int source, dst;
    }
    Synaps [] s;
```

Есть ещё и третий:

```
    class Synaps  {
        ByteBuffer b;
    }
```

Мне надо постоянно обновлять эти данные. Чтение, изменение и запись. В цикле. Какой из трёх стулов быстрее в java? Будь тут C, то второй подход был бы быстрее, это просто массив структур, который в памяти располагается близко и в цикле обрабатывается быстро. Ну в том смысле, что хорошо ложится в кэш.

Третий метод хорош при использовании opengl.

Если скорость одинакова, то я так понимаю выбрать второй вариант с переходом в третий из-за удобности подхода?

Если можно, было бы неплохо протестировать или дайте ссылку на готовое тестирование.

Comment: Второй вариант: каждый элемент - отдельный объект. Два указателя при любом доступе. Первый, третий - один указатель при доступе. Третий вариант требует аккуратности при сериализации данных. Голосую за первый.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если используется единственный экземпляр класса `Synaps` в первом варианте, то он будет лучшим компромиссом между удобством и эффективностью. Массивы примитивов - это почти самый эффективный способ представления в Java. Лучше только специализированные буферы, но с ними менее удобно работать.